# I am having trouble extracting a value from Javascript with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-match

I received the below code amongst a whole lot of HTML from a fetch in php, the code was in script tags. I am having trouble using preg_match efficiently to extract the value of `hardest27` on a certain line.

So I currently have a variable called `$html` that contains a whole lot of HTML which also contains the line below.

`$("<input>").attr({name: "levelReached", value: "hardest27" }).appendTo(newForm);`

How can I get `php` to return me the value of `levelReached`?

Comment: you want to extract value everytime or only when name is levelReached ?

Comment: only when name is levelReached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this regex over the content:

```
"levelReached"\s*,\s*value:\s*"([^"]*)"
```

group 1 contains your expected value.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/187UPB/2)

[Sample Demo Source](https://ideone.com/m9tRGx):

```
preg_match_all($re, $html, $matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $matchgroup)
    echo $matchgroup."\n";
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot :)